# Bootstrap 3, Three-column fixed layout breaks in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried everything within my repetoire to fix this.  I fall on my knees with open hands!

You can view a draft of the page here:

[www.barrettcv.com/draft_so.html](http://www.barrettcv.com/draft_so.html)

**If you would like the gist of how the page should work, simply view it in Firefox (with browser window smaller than 992 and scroll down.  The side panels start off attached, and then 'fix' to become static while the rest of the content moves.  This is the correct behaviour**

- Main problem.

The problem arises in Chrome.  When the menu column and the details column 'fix,' (scroll down the page a little) all digital hell breaks loose.

- Secondary problem.

When the view window is about 1200px, the space between the menu column and the main content panel doubles up.  This isn't as big a deal as the first problem (which has had me attempting to destroy my flat's retaining wall with my forehead) - but it's got me relatively flumoxed, as I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution that forcing it back into position with media queries

Comment: The left and right column are supposed to be displayed at all times? i.e: Their position should be fixed?

Comment: Any reason for reordering the columns with the `-pull-` `-push-` classes? Take those out and declare the columns in the actual order you want and it seems to work in Chrome (just hacked this in the dev tools).

Comment: They are like that because I want the layout to start off [menu]-[content]-[details] and then collapse down to form a column in descending order, [details]-[menu]-[content]

Comment: Hmm, I can't make that work Waclock.

To answer your question:
The positions are static until the top of the header is reached, and then the position swaps to fix. :)

Comment: Any more ideas anyone?!  In a real fix with this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are coming up against an issue in how the different browsers calculate the position of fixed position elements when no positional CSS properties are defined for the element e.g. `top` and `left`. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width):

> ...user agents are free to make a guess at its probable position.
>
> For the purposes of calculating the static position, the containing
>   block of fixed positioned elements is the initial containing block
>   instead of the viewport...

I think the only way around this is to choose a different positioning scheme. You can remove the `.col-md-pull-*` and `.col-md-push-*` classes and reposition the Bootstrap columns by using absolute positioning (depending on media queries to arrange those columns how you want for different viewport sizes). In this case it appears all browsers honour the position of the fixed element.

```
.row {
  position: relative;
}

/* apply to the details column */
.push-9 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%;
}
```

Example: http://bootply.com/92096

Comment: Wow, this is everything I could have hoped for.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to `fix` both left and right column, starting from that you will have a much better way of controlling your divs (since you want them fixed as I can see).

So, sumarizing: you need to add `position:fixed` to both your left and right columns. Modify your `left: x%` and `right: x%` so that they match your criteria.